# Bootstrap 4 Modal backdrop remains after Modal is closed

Tags: bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-4

Hi everyone I am using Bootstrap 4 Modal inside my Razor view, inside that Modal there is a Link when i click on that link an Ajax call is made , and before that Ajax call I close the modal using this code :

```
$("#oppDateModal").modal('hide');
```

everything works fine but when i click on the link the ajax call is made the Modal is closed but the page is still on the background it is like the Modal is still opened.

This is a screen shot of the page after the Modal is closed , and the stranger thing is that behavior changes , sometimes the page returns to its normal state when the Modal is closed and sometimes it stays in the background.

Does anyone know the problem and how to fix it ??

[image: ScreenShot of the page after closing the Modal]

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the problem by adding this code :

```
$("#oppDateModal").modal('hide');
    $("#oppDateModal").hide();
    $('.modal-backdrop').hide();
    $("body").removeClass("modal-open");
```

Comment: this works, but when I am trying to reopen the modal being on same page only overlay comes not the modal

Answer (score 0):

use

```
location.reload();
```

after hiding modal. This will automatically reload the page

if you dont wanna reload the page
use

```
$('.modal-backdrop').remove();
```

this will remove the back-drop